# Tax rates when C-Corporation pays salary to the owner who is non-US resident & non-US citizen

Tags: united-states, taxes, non-resident, corporation, florida

I am non-US resident and non-US citizen (i.e. NRA, nonresident alien). I would like to open C-Corporation in Florida. I would be the only owner and shareholder of the C-Corp.

I know what are the Federal Corporation Tax on profits, but I cannot find what would be the approximate Payroll taxes if I decided to pay myself a salary (i.e. C-Corp pays a salary to the NRA owner of the Corp).

**Let's use an example:**

- C-Corporation's INCOME per year is $130K
- Business EXPENSES (no salaries): $70K
- Left: $60K

Let's say C-Corporation pays the $40K per year in salaries for me (the owner).

**[Q1]**
What taxes and how much $ C-Corporation would need to pay IRS from the $40K owner's salary?

**[Q2]**
What taxes and how much $ I would need to pay in US for receiving the salary from the C-Corp?

**[Q3]**
If owner decides to withdraw $40K per year as "Owner's Draw", then this amount will be taxed by the Federal Corporation Tax only, is that correct?

Thank you!

Note: I am neither a resident nor a citizen of US.

Comment: What country are you a resident of? Will the corporation operate in Florida? Consider that any draw you receive from the corporation will probably also be taxed in your home country. Maybe as a dividend, maybe as salary, maybe as 'Other/Interest'. Depends on the tax treaty that country has with the US. It is likely that you will get a tax credit from one country that prevents double-taxation, but the timing of that credit may not match the timing of tax on the other side, which means double-taxes in similar scenarios do sometimes happen.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My country does have income tax treaty. But I more interested to understand what US taxes the corporation needs to pay and what personal taxes US might ask me to pay on owner's salary.
And corporation will not physically operate in Florida. It is for the Online Business, and I will not do anything from US. However, I will have people from US buying my digital products.